# fast rasterization on with opencl

Tags: opengl, graphics, opencl, rasterizing

i am writing a rasterizer for real-time 3d rendering with opencl.

my current architecture:

- vertex shader: 1 thread per vertex
- rasterizer: 1 thread per face that loops over all pixels covered by the face
- fragment shader: 1 thread per pixel

this works well when the faces occupy a small screen space but when i have one covering a large portion of the screen, the frame rate tanks on account of the fact that the rasterization thread must synchronously loop over all pixels the face covers.

I think this could be solved by a tiled approach. The screen would be divided into subsections (tiles), and one thread would be launched per tile. Only the faces whose bounding box overlap the tile would be processed.

I have some questions about this method though:

- Should I find the tile's overlapping faces the CPU or GPU?
- What data structure should be used to store the face lists? They will have variable length, however I believe OpenCL buffers are fixed length.

Sample of host code of current implementation:

```cpp
// set up vertex shader args
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(vertexShader, cl::NullRange, numVerts, cl::NullRange);

// set up rasterizer args
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(rasterizer, cl::NullRange, numFaces, cl::NullRange);

// set up fragment shader args
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(fragmentShader, cl::NullRange, numPixels, cl::NullRange);

// read frame buffer to draw to screen
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_screen, CL_TRUE, 0, width * height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char), screen);
```

Sample of rasterizer kernel:

```cpp
float2 bboxmin = (float2)(INFINITY,INFINITY);
float2 bboxmax = (float2)(-INFINITY,-INFINITY);

float2 clampCoords = (float2)(width-1, height-1);

// get bounding box
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        bboxmin[j] = max(0.f, min(bboxmin[j], vs[i][j]));
        bboxmax[j] = min(clampCoords[j], max(bboxmax[j], vs[i][j]));
    }
}

// loop over all pixels in bounding box
// this is the part that needs to be improved
int2 pix;
for (pix.x=bboxmin.x; pix.x<=bboxmax.x; pix.x++) {
    for (pix.y=bboxmin.y; pix.y<=bboxmax.y; pix.y++) {
        float3 bc_screen  = barycentric(vs[0].xy, vs[1].xy, vs[2].xy, (float2)(pix.x,pix.y), offset);
        float3 bc_clip    = (float3)(bc_screen.x/vsVP[0][3], bc_screen.y/vsVP[1][3], bc_screen.z/vsVP[2][3]);

        bc_clip = bc_clip/(bc_clip.x+bc_clip.y+bc_clip.z);

        float frag_depth = dot(homoZs, bc_clip);
        int pixInd = pix.x+pix.y*width;

        if (bc_screen.x<0 || bc_screen.y<0 || bc_screen.z<0 || zbuffer[pixInd]>frag_depth) continue;

        zbuffer[pixInd] = frag_depth;

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have an idea to try!

Comment: Is it correct, that you have written the rasterizer in opencl instead of OpenGL?

Comment: That is correct. OpenGL’s rasterizer is not programmable, so I am implementing it in OpenCL to expose some parameters.

Comment: I don't know if you mix concepts or you are trying something very exotic. In the second case, I suggest you to add some good portion of code and images to illustrate your problem.

Comment: If you _really_ need to write your own rasterizer instead of using the GPUs special (and very elaborate) circuitry, you need to employ some parallelism o  n that task too. A single thread per face won't do.

Comment: I have posted code samples @AdrianMaire.

Comment: @derhass This is the main purpose of my question. I am unsure how to parellilize this part

Comment: Have a look at how how real hardware rasterizers might deal with it: [https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-6/](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-6/)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to cancel rasterization if a face gets too large and just return. This will lead to some visual artifacts, but at least the frame rate won't suffer.

Comment: This will not work as I would like the face to still render even if it is large.